# Is MemberInfo.MetadataToken stable across compiler runs?

Tags: c#, reflection

In our application, we need a way to uniquely identify reflection metadata objects in C#.
Reflection API has a `MemberInfo.MetadataToken` property, which is documented to fulfil this task.
However, what isn't documented is whether this token will be the same after the next build of the same module, given that module name, namespace, declaring type name, and member name are unchanged.

Does anyone know about the details of implementation of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they won't be. The metadata token value is dependant on everything else in the assembly, and the exact order which the compiler generates types in the output assembly. If the input code or project changes in *any* way whatsoever, then all the tokens could change.

Why do you need to do this?

Comment: It will be used in a generic application framework that associates extended type and member metadata with existing metadata objects accessed via Reflection. It would have been nice if there was that kind of a unique id for metadata constructs, but now that it isn't, I will reference these constructs by fully qualified name.

Comment: Thats the correct way of doing it, and is in fact how cross-assembly references are done in .NET assemblies; by the assembly name and FQN of the target type