# What is a good unique identifying property of a .NET Method Info

Tags: .net, reflection

When storing Method Info data, from a Reflection read of a set of .NET assemblies, what would be the best logical key to use from the Method Info instance, to separate it from like name Methods in different Types, or like name Methods in the same type with different parameters?

For example, a Type has the AssemblyQualifiedName property to nicely identify it from similar Types.

UPDATE: As suggested by Peter Ritchie, there is the .NET Reflection MetadataToken property, which is exactly what I was hoping for, however, according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834317/c-memberinfo-metadatatoken-stable-across-compiler-runs), this token is not maintained over subsequent compiles.

The answer appears to be, as Oded suggested, a concatenated key of: "The fully qualified name of the containing type + its name and parameters"

I am happy to hear any further suggestions

Comment: The fully qualified name of the containing type + its name and parameters?

Comment: @Oded That was my initial thought, but it felt both verbose and clunky, and was wondering if there was something available, that I was unaware of, that could take its stead. If not, I am happy to build such a key

Comment: You can always use a hash of the above if it is too long ;)

Comment: the `MethodInfo.MetadataToken` uniquely identifies an element within a module.  If that's not sufficient, maybe you can detail some of your requirements so that someone can offer an answer that can potentially be correct?

Comment: @Oded :) True, but I think I'll stick with the semantically comprehensible concatenation, as suggested

Comment: @PeterRitchie I wasn't aware of that, and was just the sort of thing I was looking for. I shall investigate, and update this accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, very nice idea, and thanks again. Unfortunately, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834317/c-memberinfo-metadatatoken-stable-across-compiler-runs, it is not maintained over subsequent compiles. This isn't necessarily an issue for what I need it for, but I like to keep it robust for possible future requirements

Comment: That would be those "requirements" I spoke of...

Comment: @PeterRitchie As a rule, I generally don't want to put too many constraints on a question, as long as the question doesn't become too broad, as I like to understand the problem domain fully. If I had stated that I would prefer a constant UID over compiles, then I would have never been pointed to, and investigated further, the MetadataToken by you. I now have a greater understanding of the area, and I thank you for that